# After updating kernel to 4.20, USB permissions denied

Tags: usb, kernel, permissions

I just updated the kernel from 4.15.0-43 to 4.20, Ubuntu 18.04
First change I noticed is that my MP3 player, /dev/sdd, does not have permissions to read or write.
I tried the following:
sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdd
It changed nothing.
I can always reboot to an older kernel, right? But short of that, what can I do?

Comment: Is there a reason why you changed to a Kernel that is still in development?  Were you having problems with the 4.15 kernel?  For something like this you would probably need to file a bug report with the developers so they can fix it.  And yes, you should always be able to load the older kernel under advanced boot in grub if you didn't uninstall the old one.

Comment: Terrance, you are right. It was only that it was new. Lesson learned. I rebooted to the previous kernel and the problem was gone.
I think I will uninstall ukuu.